# i want to import a non built in python library in a python file in ubuntu, what should i do?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I tried to download it by several ways using the ubuntu terminal and it doesn't work well as expected. the library name is pywhatkit.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is it the installation of the library (by pip I assume)? What error do you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Step one**: If you do not have a python interpreter installed, then [install a python interpreter](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. **Step Two**: If you do not already have it, install a computer program known as `pip`. One way to check if you have `pip` installed is by writing the following code inside of a command-window (the command-window is also known as a "shell emulator" or "terminal"). Type the following text into the Linux shell:
   `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`
   The computer will do one of five things:

   1. Complain that it does not know what `python` is.
   2. Complain that it does not know what `pip` is.
   3. Download `pip` from the internet and upgrade `pip` to the latest version
   4. Complain that there is no internet connection
   5. Give you some syntax error.
3. **Step Three** type the following into a shell window: `pip install pywhatkit`

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF WINDOWS COMMAND WINDOW before install]

While `pip` retrieves `pywhatkit` from the internet, `pip` will print a lot of stuff to the console, like this:

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF WINDOWS COMMAND WINDOW after install]

**Step Four** would be to write some python source code which uses the `pywhatkit` library. Something like the following:

```py
import pywhatkit

print("\n".join(filter(lambda s: s[0:1] != "_", dir(pywhatkit))))

pywhatkit.ascii_art

pywhatkit.core

pywhatkit.info

pywhatkit.take_screenshot
```